# How to subclass Java Mail Message

Tags: java, class, jakarta-mail

I am newbie to Java Mail API. Can anyone please tell me how can i subclass javamail Message because I need this to marshal and unmarshall the code. When i subclass, I have to implement a lot of functions, is this the way of subclassing? After subclassing, following snippet occurs:

```
<code>
public class MailMessage extends Message{

    @Override
    public void addHeader(String arg0, String arg1) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getAllHeaders() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getContent() throws IOException, MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DataHandler getDataHandler() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisposition() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFileName() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getHeader(String arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException, MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLineCount() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getMatchingHeaders(String[] arg0)
            throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getNonMatchingHeaders(String[] arg0)
            throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMimeType(String arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeHeader(String arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setContent(Multipart arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setContent(Object arg0, String arg1) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setDataHandler(DataHandler arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setDisposition(String arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setFileName(String arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setHeader(String arg0, String arg1) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream arg0) throws IOException,
            MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void addFrom(Address[] arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void addRecipients(RecipientType arg0, Address[] arg1)
            throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Flags getFlags() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Address[] getFrom() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getReceivedDate() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Address[] getRecipients(RecipientType arg0)
            throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Date getSentDate() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSubject() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Message reply(boolean arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveChanges() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setFlags(Flags arg0, boolean arg1) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setFrom() throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setFrom(Address arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setRecipients(RecipientType arg0, Address[] arg1)
            throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setSentDate(Date arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setSubject(String arg0) throws MessagingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
</code>
```

Comment: You can delete all the auto generated once except the once you really going to override. You need to implement all only if it is a Interface and if your calss is not abstract. But extending allow you to extend any number of methods as you want

Answer (score 2):

`MailMessage`s are created by JavaMail API so it would be hard to change it.
Consider to create a Wrapper for for `javax.mail.Message` that extends `Message` and delegates all `Message's` method to the wrapped one instead. Then add your functionality to the wrapper class.

Example:

```
public class MailMessageWrapper extends MailMessage {
    private final MailMessage msg;

    public MailMessageWrapper(MailMessage msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public void addHeader(String arg0, String arg1) throws MessagingException {
        msg.addHeader(arg0, arg1);            
    }

    // other MailMessage delagations here

    public void yourMethod() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper approach above works fine, or you can just use a "container" object:

```
public class MyMessage implements Serializable {
    public MimeMessage message;

    public MyMessage(MimeMessage message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException {
        // implement using MimeMessage(Session, InputStream) constructor
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        // implement using MimeMessage.writeTo() method
    }
}
```

Reference the real message using myMsg.message.getSubject() or whatever.